# When to use a django form and when to use a html one?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

In templates you can write forms in several ways: either by an already created Django form or by a plain html form. Both of them are okay, and can be used, so I am interested in case of using each form. I've used `ModelForm` several times and it's a really nice shortcut, also I am reading a Django book and Django forms are introduced as a good way of validation, even if you won't use them in your templates. But also many tutorials show html forms where a django froms are expected (at least for me). An example in a search form. All of the tutorials I've seen use plain html form, capture a query and return a queryset. Why wouldn't they write a separate form and use it as `{{ SearchForm }}`?

Comment: Django's **generic** views are exactly that, **generic**.  If you want full, true control over what is being displayed then you have to write it out yourself.  Especially when you start mixing in jQuery, AJAX, CSS, and other things that modify the DOM once it has been served.  There are a lot of extensions to work with and around these limitations but ultimately there's no way to control it fully unless you write it fully.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Personally, I never use `{{ form.field }}` syntax in my templates. I always write HTML for my forms. Because it is easy to assign classes, ids and other data attributes to form inputs in HTML rather than doing the same in forms.py

When you need to assign classes and ids to form inputs, you will need to do something like this:

```
myfield = forms.CharField(
    widget=forms.TextArea(
        attrs={'class': 'some-class', 
           'id': 'SomeId',
           'rows': '10',
           'style': 'margin-top: 10px;',
        }
    )
)
```

Frankly, it sucks. Now compare the above code with this:

```
<textarea name="myfield" rows="10" class="some-class" id="SomeId" style="margin-top: 10px;"></textarea>
```

And now your Django code can get a little shorter, thereby cleaner:

```
myfield = forms.CharField()
```

The HTML syntax is far better than corresponding Python syntax. It feels more natural. Also, if you've got a designer working with you on a project who doesn't know Python, this way you both won't interfere with each other's development process.

Comment: But when do I need to create a Django Form in `forms.py` and when I can just use an html one with? For example I want to create an 'send us a letter' form, do I need to create the form in `forms.py` and then represent it in template somehow?

Comment: @pythad That depends on how heavily you want to validate the form. If the validation is simple and can be done in one or two lines, I wouldn't bother creating a form class for it.